# Code highlighting between tags?

Tags: javascript, codehighlighter

I should give possibility user select code in his comments, I think good way will be say him put his code in something like this `<code></code>`, I found many plugins for code highlighting, but not one give possibility highlight code only between tags, it there a way highlight code only between tags?

Comment: If the user selects code you mean that he clicks on it? If thats the case you could attach an event listener to process the highlight on the element clicked

Comment: No, I mean he put this in his comments text.

Comment: 123.. extract the content from the tag, format that part, put it back together.

Comment: When I extract content of the node it is parsing as html and "<iostream.h>" is translated as tag, and content is changed, the only way I see is parse string and highlight only what I need, but this way isn't easy and will have many bugs.

Comment: Now I use not google prettify, but hasn't got any sense, because code that I give to highlighter is highlighting correct, the problem is I can't extract correct code and replace it.